# Incorrect query filter according to the requirement

Tags: oracle

My requirement wholly depends on the `QUERY`.

I am filtering my gridview on the basis of `three parameters`.

1. `Project_name` (Always required)
2. `Date` (Not always)
3. `Vehicle_No` (Not always)

So, what my requirement is,

> With `project_name` either any one can be used for filtering my gridview.

Currently my debugged query works exactly fine for any two parameters.

Below is my debugged query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no,
               TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_in vehicleindate_time,
               TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_out vehicleoutdate_time,
            gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno,
            gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight,
               TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || challan_no challandate_no,
            remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in
       FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv,
            xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd,
            xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms
      WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type)
        AND (       sv.project_id = '1368'
                AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = '26-11-2015'
             OR vehicle_no = '0'
            )
        AND sv.delete_flag = 'N'
   ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no
```

The above query shows me the exact result for `project_name` and `Date` which I entered.

But when I add the third parameter say `Vehicle_no` it doesn't show the data for that exact `vehicle_no` it still shows me the same data which I looked for `2` parameters.

I am using Oracle for the database.

**LATEST UPDATE WHICH IS NOT WORKING**

I am confused as how to deal with the query, as Balazs' solution was working fine when I selected, `Project_name`, `Date` and then `vehicle_no` (not necessary). But it was not fetching proper result when I took first as `Project_name`, and `Vehicle_no`. Any guesses why?

> The issue  is when I only filter with `Project_name` and `Vehicle_no` the date_column value comes as `0` so it doesn't show me any row, which is incorrect as I have data for that `Project_name` and `Vehicle_no`.

I have used `Balaz's` second query for the solution which is below

```
WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type)
    AND (       sv.project_id = '1368'
            AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = '26-11-2015'
         AND vehicle_no = decode(:vehicle_no, '0', vehicle_no, :vehicle_no)
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the below bind variable substitution:

```
AND ( sv.project_id                 = DECODE(:'  1368','0', project_id, :'1368')
AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = DECODE(:'  ', '0', date_in, :'  ')
AND vehicle_no                      = DECODE(:'  GJ-06-0Z-9202', '0', vehicle_no, :'  GJ-06-0Z-9202') ))
```

Your application should pass the value to the bind variable correctly. The query you need to use is:

```
AND sv.project_id = DECODE(:project_id, 0, project_id, :project_id) 
AND date_in       = DECODE(:date_in, 0, date_in, :date_in) 
AND vehicle_no    = DECODE(:vehicle_no, 0, vehicle_no, :vehicle_no)
```

The above **DECODE** is just like an **IF-ELSE** construct. It means, if the passed values are `0`, then use the **column value** from the table, else, use the **value** that is passed.

Your application need to assign values to the following bind variables:

- :project_id
- :date_in
- :vehicle_no

For example, in **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> var num number
SQL> exec :num := 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print num

       NUM
----------
        10

SQL> var text varchar2(10)
SQL> exec :text := 'coder'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print text

TEXT
--------------------------------
coder
```

Also, no need to use **TO_CHAR** for the **DATE**. Pass the value as **DATE**. Else, use **TO_DATE** on the **literal** on the right hand side. Leave the date as it is, since you should compare the dates and not strings. TO_CHAR converts the date into string in your desired format. You need TO_CHAR only to display the date, not while comparing or date arithmetic.

**UPDATE** :

Your application should pass the value to the bind variable properly. After passing the value, your query still has the bind variable symbol `:`.

> :'  1368'

If you capture the bind variable value, then it should just be:

> '1368'

Also, there is a **leading space** in the value. Although, it won't throw any error, it would give you incorrect output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict the resultset based on the `vehicle_no`, then use `AND` instead of `OR`.

```
 WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type)
        AND (       sv.project_id = '1368'
                AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = '26-11-2015'
 --->        OR vehicle_no = '0'
            )
```

You could use something like this, though I am not a fan of code like this:

```
 WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type)
        AND (       sv.project_id = '1368'
                AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = '26-11-2015'
             AND vehicle_no = decode(:vehicle_no, '0', vehicle_no, :vehicle_no)
            )
```

You can use the above little trick on other parameters as well.

```
WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type)
    AND (
         sv.project_id = decode(:project_id, '0', project_id, :project_id)
         AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = decode(:date_in, '0', date_in, :date_in)
         AND vehicle_no = decode(:vehicle_no, '0', vehicle_no, :vehicle_no)
        )
```

Where variables starting with `:` are bind variables, so that is where you bind your actual values.

And this is really bad practice:

```
TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = '26-11-2015'
```

You should compare same datatypes. If you must convert different datatypes, converting the constant or bind variable is way better. The above prevents using a regular index on the `date_in` column because of the conversino. Do it like this:

```
date_in = to_date('26-11-2015', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

After so much of thinking about logic and `OPERATORS` what I simply did was

first I created a simple `string` in my code like below

`string date = txtdatefilter.Text;`

in which I will assign the value of `date` textbox.

My main issue was, I was not able to decode my `date` values. So I checked the condition in my `C#` code like below:-

```
if (date == "")
    {

        // Query if date was not added [Only difference was **OR** operator] here
    }

    else
    {
        //// Query if date was not added [Only difference was **AND** operator here]
    }
```

And the query was

```
if (date == "")
    {

        strquerry = "SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no, TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') || ' & ' || time_in vehicleindate_time, TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd-MM-yyyy') || ' & ' " +
                 "|| time_out vehicleoutdate_time, gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno, gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight, TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy') " +
                 "|| ' & ' || challan_no challandate_no,remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv, xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd, " +
                 "xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type) " +
                 "AND(sv.project_id = '" + cmbProjectName.SelectedValue + "'  AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = '" + txtdatefilter.Text + "' " +
                 "OR vehicle_no = decode('" + ddlVehicleno.SelectedValue + "', '0', vehicle_no, '" + ddlVehicleno.SelectedValue + "')) AND sv.delete_flag = 'N' ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no";
    }

    else
    {
        strquerry = "SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no, TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') || ' & ' || time_in vehicleindate_time, TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd-MM-yyyy') || ' & ' " +
                "|| time_out vehicleoutdate_time, gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno, gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight, TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy') " +
                "|| ' & ' || challan_no challandate_no,remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv, xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd, " +
                "xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type) " +
                "AND(sv.project_id = '" + cmbProjectName.SelectedValue + "'  AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = '" + txtdatefilter.Text + "' " +
                "AND vehicle_no = decode('" + ddlVehicleno.SelectedValue + "', '0', vehicle_no, '" + ddlVehicleno.SelectedValue + "')) AND sv.delete_flag = 'N' ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no";
    }
```

I thought of doing it by creating a function, but i was rather preferring my `C#` code for this.

That resolved my query

**Any answer better than this would be most welcomed**